# php-ews: Class 'SoapClient' not found when using full path to the Classes

Tags: php, composer-php, php-ews

Implementing `php-ews` on the existing non-OOP website.

Running standalone PHP script in shell works fine.

Standalone PHP script uses `use`:

```
use \jamesiarmes\PhpEws\Client;
use \jamesiarmes\PhpEws\Request\CreateItemType;
```

But I can't use `use` inside if-statements on the website, so I prepended all Classes using full path (i.e. `new \jamesiarmes\PhpEws\Client`).

Now I'm getting this error.

`Fatal error: Class 'SoapClient' not found in /home/project/master/vendor/jamesiarmes/php-ntlm/src/SoapClient.php on line 13`

I verified that Soap extension is installed. Please help. Thanks.

```
if ($_REQUEST['action'] == 'export-form-test') {

    require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

/*
use \jamesiarmes\PhpEws\Client;
use \jamesiarmes\PhpEws\Request\CreateItemType;

use \jamesiarmes\PhpEws\ArrayType\NonEmptyArrayOfAllItemsType;
use \jamesiarmes\PhpEws\ArrayType\NonEmptyArrayOfAttendeesType;

use \jamesiarmes\PhpEws\Enumeration\BodyTypeType;
use \jamesiarmes\PhpEws\Enumeration\CalendarItemCreateOrDeleteOperationType;
use \jamesiarmes\PhpEws\Enumeration\ResponseClassType;
use \jamesiarmes\PhpEws\Enumeration\RoutingType;

use \jamesiarmes\PhpEws\Type\AttendeeType;
use \jamesiarmes\PhpEws\Type\BodyType;
use \jamesiarmes\PhpEws\Type\CalendarItemType;
use \jamesiarmes\PhpEws\Type\EmailAddressType;
*/

    // Replace this with your desired start/end times and guests.
    $start = new DateTime('tomorrow 4:00pm');
    $end = new DateTime('tomorrow 5:00pm');

    // Set connection information.
    $host = '*********';
    $username = '*******';
    $password = '********';
    //$version = Client::VERSION_2016;

    $client = new \jamesiarmes\PhpEws\Client($host, $username, $password);

    // Build the request,
    $request = new \jamesiarmes\PhpEws\Request\CreateItemType();
    $request->SendMeetingInvitations = \jamesiarmes\PhpEws\Enumeration\CalendarItemCreateOrDeleteOperationType::SEND_ONLY_TO_ALL;
    $request->Items = new \jamesiarmes\PhpEws\ArrayType\NonEmptyArrayOfAllItemsType();

    // Build the event to be added.
    $event = new \jamesiarmes\PhpEws\Type\CalendarItemType();
    $event->Start = $start->format('c');
    $event->End = $end->format('c');
    $event->title = 'EWS Test Event';

    // Set the event body.
    $event->Body = new \jamesiarmes\PhpEws\Type\BodyType();
    $event->Body->_ = 'This is the event body';
    $event->Body->BodyType = \jamesiarmes\PhpEws\Enumeration\BodyTypeType::TEXT;

    // Add the event to the request. You could add multiple events to create more
    // than one in a single request.
    $request->Items->CalendarItem[] = $event;

    $response = $client->CreateItem($request);

    // Iterate over the results, printing any error messages or event ids.
    $response_messages = $response->ResponseMessages->CreateItemResponseMessage;
    foreach($response_messages as $response_message) {
        // Make sure the request succeeded.
        if ($response_message->ResponseClass != ResponseClassType::SUCCESS) {
            $return_arr['status'] = 'error';
            continue;
        }

        // Iterate over the created events, printing the id for each.
        foreach($response_message->Items->CalendarItem as $item) {
            $id = $item->ItemId->Id;
            $return_arr['status'] = 'ok';
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What are the PHP versions on the server and on your machine? Where is the 'vendor/autoload.php' file from? Could you include or link its source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Running standalone PHP script in shell works fine.

but

> I verified that Soap extension is installed.

How have you verified? You know you may be loading different `php.ini` files for CLI and Webserver environments.

(For example, in my Ubuntu server, with Apache webserver, I have both

`/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`

and

`/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` )

Comment: php-fpm wasn't restarted properly, while CLI was okay. Stupid... =)

Answer (score 1):

Not answering your original question, but this one:

> But I can't use use inside if-statements on the website, so I prepended all Classes using full path (i.e. new \jamesiarmes\PhpEws\Client).

`use` statements to import namespaced classes belong to the top of the file, outside any parentheses. They will always be "executed", i.e. create alias links inside the current namespace for the foreign class name (and if no namespace is being used, the root namespace is being used) - just for the current file they are in. So it is nothing permanent or reaching outside of the current file - new files may have different `use` imports, but they also have to repeat any imports if a class is being used in both files.

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php for the chapter on namespaces at large and http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php for using `use` in particular. Note example 5 with an illegal code:

```
<?php
namespace Languages;

function toGreenlandic()
{
    use Languages\Danish;

    // ...
}
?>
```

Importing classes with `use` is independent from the execution of code. It already happens when parsing the file to allow PHP to know the fully qualified name of all classes that are being used in the code. They will only be autoloaded when the code gets executed, but `use` should be kept at the top of the file.

Comment: What if I don't use `function() {}` ? Does `Languages` namespace has to match whatever is pre-loaded with `vendors/autoload`?

Comment: `use` cannot be used inside functions, classes or if blocks. And you always have to provide the full namespace, there are no shortcuts possible. However, after having used `use`, you can reference the imported class just by it's name without a leading backslash, or by its alias name if you gave one.